# Converting a hex encoded iso 8583 message to json using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, iso8583

I am using this library: https://github.com/zemuldo/iso_8583 to try parse and dump an ISO 8583 message.

The **code**:

```
var bitMapData = '0210723A40010AE18002005000990000000750001002102636000000172636100210036014045016000042 (i'am using this library https://github.com/zemuldo/iso_8583)667818001               000000000TS0002tester                                  0490823 75551512000000075000000000010051003915030257360006133001';

const config = {
    lenHeader: false, 
    lenHeaderEncoding: 'utf8', 
    bitmapEncoding: 'utf8', 
    secondaryBitmap: false, 
    hasSpecialFields: true,
};

let incoming = new Iso_8583().getIsoJSON(
    new Buffer.alloc(bitMapData.length, bitMapData),
    config
    );

console.log(incoming)
```

**result of code**:

```
{   
        '0': '0210',   
        '2': '00100210263600000017263610021003601404501600004266',   
        '3': '781800', 
        '4': '1',   
        '7': '    000000',   
        '11': '000TS0',   
        '12': '002tes',   
        '13': 'ter ',   
        '15': '    ',   
        '18': '    ',   
        '32': '',  
        '37': '            ',   
        '39': '  ',   
        '41': '        ',   
        '42': ' 0490823 755515',   
        '43': '1200000007500000000001005100391503025736',   
        '48': '',   
        '49': '613',   
        '63': '1',   
        '74': '',   
        '76': '',   
        '89': '',   
        '92': '',   
        '93': '',   
        '96': '',   
        '126': '',   
        '128': ''  
    }
```

**Result what I need**:

```
{  
    '0': '0201',  
    '2': '',  
    '3': '500099',  
    '4': '000000075000',  
    '7': '1002102636',  
    '11': '000000',  
    '12': '172636',   
    '13': '1002',  
    '15': '1003',  
    '18': '6014',  
    '32': '5016',  
    '37': '000042667818',  
    '39': '00',  
    '41': '1',  
    '42': '000000000TS0002',  
    '43': 'tester',  
    '48': '0823 75551512000000075000000000010051003915030257',  
    '49': '360',   
    '63': '133001' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something weird is going on, it the above code really exactly what you are running?

The message is:

```
0210723A40010AE180020050009900000007500010021026360...
```

The MTI (returned in bit 0 of the dump) is clearly:

```
0210723A40010AE180020050009900000007500010021026360...
----
```

"0210", so it's strange that your example should return 0201? What makes you believe that that is the case.

Moving on, the bitmap (the actual bitmap at the start of the message that indicates what fields are present in the message) is:

```
0210723A40010AE180020050009900000007500010021026360...
    ----------------
```

it starts with '72' so the first bit is zero (the first byte 0x72 is 0111 0010). This is strange, because the dump you posted indicates that fields beyond field 64 are set. This is not possible without a secondary bitmap. As a secondary bitmap would be indicated by the first bit of the primary bitmap being set and you explicitly disable the secondary bitmap in the options this is not the expected behaviour.

From what I can tell, the rest of the problems arise from the parser interpreting the next 8 bytes as the secondary bitmap and shifting things around:

```
0210723A40010AE180020050009900000007500010021026360...
                    ----------------
```

Field #2 is now ( just guessing ) being interpreted as a 50 char (BCD) field starting with 0010021 ...:

```
0210723A40010AE180020050009900000007500010021026360...
                                    ------------>  ...
```

This leads me to believe there are things going on that aren't mentioned in the post.

Comment: thanks to your response. That is original iso 8583 response message from server. I'am new using iso 8583. I think that iso 8583 response message already customed by server. I just find one library and implement that but the result not same what i need. Do you have suggestion for my problem?

Comment: Like I said below, you need to find out why the library thinks a secondary bitmap is present. Further Suggestions: not all iso dialects are the same, you may need some custom field definitions. Which iso dialect are you trying to parse? From where do you have the "proper" response?

Comment: base of documentation, there not mention iso dialect like omnipay,openway,etc. I got the message from server. I just send request and get response like that.
this is my request, 0200723A400108E180020050009900000007500010021026360000001726361002100360140450160000426678181               
000000000TS0002tester                                  0250823 75551512000000075000360006133001